# Functional way to take element in a list until a limit in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The aim of the method is to take elements in a list until a limit is reached.

e.g.

I've come up with 2 different implementations

```
def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int): List[Int] = {
  var sum = 0
  l.takeWhile { e =>
    sum += e
    sum <= limit
  }
}
```

It is straightforward, but a mutable state is used.

```
def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int): List[Int] = {
  val summed = l.toStream.scanLeft(0) { case (e, sum) => sum + e }
  l.take(summed.indexWhere(_ > limit) - 1)
}
```

It seems cleaner, but it's more verbose and perhaps less memory efficient because a stream is needed.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also do that in a single pass with a fold:

```
  def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int): List[Int] =
    l.fold((List.empty[Int], 0)) { case ((res, acc), next) =>
      if (acc + next > limit)
        (res, limit)
      else
        (next :: res, next + acc)
    }
```

Because the standard lists aren't lazy, and neither is fold, this will always traverse the entire list. One alternative would be to use [cats' `iteratorFoldM`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/388acd1e364622af03e1bfeb298388305d703039/core/src/main/scala/cats/Foldable.scala#L460) instead for an implementation that short circuits once the limit is reached.

You could also write the short circuiting fold directly using tail recursion, something along those lines:

```
def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int): List[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def take0(list: List[Int], accList: List[Int], accSum: Int) : List[Int] =
    list match {
      case h :: t if accSum + h < limit =>  
        take0(t, h :: accList, h + accSum)
      case _ => accList
    }
  take0(l, Nil, 0).reverse
}
```

Note that this second solution might be faster, but also less elegant as it requires additional effort to prove that the implementation terminates, something obvious when using a fold.

Comment: Regarding your second method : there is a small typo, it's `take0` on L6. And the list is returned in reverse order. Scala is missing a foldWhile in the standard lib, wdyt ?

Answer (score 4):

The first way is perfectly fine as the result of your function is still perfectly immutable.

On a side note, this is actually how many functions of the scala collection library are implemented, they create a mutable builder for efficiency and return an immutable collection out of it.

Comment: I saw a few answers from you, good ones! thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the kind, encouraging words.

Answer (score 1):

A functional way is to use recursive function and make sure it is stack safe.

If you just use basic scala:

```
    import scala.annotation.tailrec
    def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int) : List[Int] = {
      @tailrec
      def takeHelper(l:List[Int], limit:Int, r:List[Int]):List[Int] =
        l match {
            case h::t if (h <= limit ) =>  takeHelper(t, limit-h, r:+h)
            case _ =>  r
      }
      takeHelper(l, limit, Nil)
    }
```

If you can use scalaz Trampoline, it is a bit nicer:

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.Scalaz._
import Free._
 def take(l: List[Int], limit: Int): Trampoline[List[Int]] = {

    l match {
      case h :: t if (h <= limit) => suspend(take(t, limit - h)).map(h :: _)


     case _                      => return_(Nil)
    }
  }
  println(take(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1), 10).run)
  println(take(List.fill(10000)(1), 100000000).run)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your second version is already pretty good.  You might tweak it a little, like this:

```
val sums = l.toStream.scanLeft(0){_ + _} drop 1
l zip sums takeWhile {_._2 <= limit} map (_._1)
```

This way you aren't dealing with indices, which is usually a little easier to follow.

Comment: Good, but zipping isn't required: `val sums=l.toStream.scan(0)(_+_);
l.take(sums.lastIndexWhere(_<=limit))`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend your own customize way, you could also use something like:

```
def custom(con: => Boolean)(i: Int)(a: => List[Int])(body: => Unit): List[Int] = {
      if (con) {
        body
        custom(con)(i + 1)(a)(body)
      }
      else {
        a.slice(0, i)
      }
    }
```

then call it like this:

```
var j = 100
    val t = customTake(j > 80)(0)((0 to 99).toList) {
      j -= 1
    }
    println(t)
```